# Find the number of ways of arranging chess pieces.

Tags: probability

In a particular chess variant, the pieces are placed randomly in a row behind the
pawns. Determine the number of possible ways a player’s pieces can follow all of these rules:
 There are 8 pieces (a King, a Queen, two Rooks, two Knights, and two Bishops)
 The two Bishops must go on opposite colors squares (Note: squares alternate
between dark and light)
 The King must go between the two Rooks (though the other pieces can also be
between them)
 The Queen and Knights have no restrictions

Answer (score 1):

Let's see... the dark-squared bishop can go on any of $4$ squares, as can the light-squared bishop. Then the queen has $6$ squares left it can go on and the knights have $\binom{5}{2}=10$ possible placements. After that the placement of the king and the rooks is fixed so there are
$$4\times4\times6\times10=960$$
ways to configure each player's pieces.

Comment: thank you so much. :)